# Kotlin - failed to get location address in real device

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kotlin, android-service

I'm in trouble with my little app .

I want to get address location with geocoding-reverse in android studio .

but my code is work just in the emulator . when i conncet my real dvice with app and want to get the address it gives me the error and app crashed . the error : grpc failed .

I put my code in try and catch method but the error still remain .

here is my little app :

the menifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.my_test_app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCutiOvAqZiLvka-kW9B12K.........." />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="text1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="button"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        />



</RelativeLayou
```

main activiy :

```
package com.example.my_test_app

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Address
import android.location.Geocoder
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private val requestcode = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)



        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        button.setOnClickListener {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {

                getlocation()


            } else {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                    ),
                    requestcode
                )

                return@setOnClickListener

            }


        }

    }

    private fun getlocation() {

        fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(this) { location ->


            if (location != null) {

                val lat = location.latitude
                val long = location.longitude

                val geocoder = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault())

                try {

                    val address: List<Address> = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, long, 1)

                    textview1.text = address[0].maxAddressLineIndex.toString()
                    textview2.text = address[0].getAddressLine(0).toString()


                } catch (e: Exception) {

                    Toast.makeText(this, e.message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }


            } else {


                Toast.makeText(this, "موقعیت پیدا نشد ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }

        }


    }


}
```

So , what is wrong with my code ? what is the Grpc error meaning ?

If i put the geo code in back thread the issue would resolve or not ?

can anyone help with this ?

I use the debug api key not release.

thank's for help .

Answer (score 0):

Geocoder needs to be called apart from the main thread of your app.

Geocoder is synchronous and may take a long time to do its work, so you `should not call it from the main user interface (UI) thread` of your app.

Try with `AsyncTask`..

also check whether you have good internet and not using proxy..

Comment: I searched and AsyncTask is deprecate . do you have any idea what i have to do for doing the code in background ?